# ActiveDataProvider

Tags: php, yii2

Есть запрос, который возвращает данные, например:

```
id юл. лица,                      юр.лицо,               заказ
 1                                  ИП Иванов           21
 1                                  ИП Иванов           22
 2                                  ИП Петров           33
```

Если передаю запрос в ActiveDataProvider, а потом вывожу все в GridView отображаются только 2 записи:

```
id юл. лица,                      юр.лицо,               заказ
 1                                  ИП Иванов           22
 2                                  ИП Петров           33
```

ActiveDataProvider фильтрует псевдо-одинаковые строки.
Как это запретить? мне нужны все строки.

```
        $query = self::find()->alias('c')
        ->select(['c.client_id', 'c.client_title',
            'inn' => 'inn.detail_value',
            'contract' => 'contr.client_title',
            'order' => 'order.client_title',
            'address' => 'address.detail_value',
            'dateEndContract' => 'dateEndContract.detail_value',
        ])
        ->leftJoin(['inn' => 'client_details'],
            [
                'inn.detail_type' => DetailType::TYPE_INN,
                'inn.detail_client_id' => new Expression('c.client_id'),
                'inn.detail_status' => Detail::STATUS_ACTIVE
            ]
        )
        ->leftJoin(['cdsub' => 'client_details'],
            [
                'cdsub.detail_type' => DetailType::TYPE_SUBCONTRACT,
                'cdsub.detail_client_id' => new Expression('c.client_id'),
                'cdsub.detail_status' => Detail::STATUS_ACTIVE
            ]
        )
        ->leftJoin(['cdcontr' => 'client_details'],
            [
                'cdcontr.detail_type' => DetailType::TYPE_PERSONAL_ACCOUNT,
                'cdcontr.detail_value' => new Expression('cdsub.detail_value'),
                'cdcontr.detail_status' => Detail::STATUS_ACTIVE
            ]
        )
        ->leftJoin(['contr' => 'clients'],
            [
                'contr.client_type' => ClientTypeList::TYPE_CONTRACT,
                'contr.client_id' => new Expression('cdcontr.detail_client_id'),
                'contr.client_status' => Detail::STATUS_ACTIVE
            ]
        )
        ->leftJoin(['cdorder' => 'client_details'],
            [
                'cdorder.detail_type' => DetailType::TYPE_PARENT,
                'cdorder.detail_value' => new Expression('cdcontr.detail_value'),
                'cdorder.detail_status' => Detail::STATUS_ACTIVE
            ]
        )
        ->leftJoin(['order' => 'clients'],
            [
                'order.client_type' => ClientTypeList::TYPE_ORDER,
                'order.client_id' => new Expression('cdorder.detail_client_id'),
                'order.client_status' => Detail::STATUS_ACTIVE
            ]
        )
        ->leftJoin(['address' => 'client_details'],
            [
                'address.detail_client_id' => new Expression('IFNULL(order.client_id, contr.client_id)'),
                'address.detail_type' => DetailType::TYPE_LEGAL_ENTITY_ADDRESS,
                'address.detail_status' => Detail::STATUS_ACTIVE
            ]
        )
        ->leftJoin(['dateEndContract' => 'client_details'],
            [
                'dateEndContract.detail_client_id' => new Expression('IFNULL(order.client_id, contr.client_id)'),
                'dateEndContract.detail_type' => DetailType::TYPE_CONTRACT_DATE_END,
                'dateEndContract.detail_status' => Detail::STATUS_ACTIVE
            ]
        )
        ->where([
            'c.client_type' => $this->validationRange
        ]);

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 50
        ],
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение следующее - Вычесляемый ключ (как по инструкции).

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
            'key' => function ($model) {
                return md5($model->order);
            },
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => 50
            ],
        ]);
```

Но обязательно, нужно в запросе убрать из выборки поле id (в моем случае c.client_id).
Тогда работает.